# Best practices for adding/editing data using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I am currently developing an SPA application using AngularJS which allows end-users to add & edit orders via a form.

What I would like to know is what is considered the best practice for determining whether the application is in an `Edit` or `Create` state?

For example, when I click on a menu item that says 'Add New Order' I would expect a partial view called `order.html' displayed with all entry fields blank.  If it's possible, I would also like is to re-use this same view when editing an order with the entry fields pre-filled from the current order being edited.

Do I need to use a `service/factory` for this that has a property to determine state, for example:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('orderService', ['$http', function($http) {
        var state = {
            addOrder: false,
            order: {
                orderRef: "",
                orderDate: ""
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Then I could set the `addOrder` property from the relevant controller according to the edit state, as well as filling out the `order` property with the details of the order when `addOrder: true`.

I have looked around the net, unfortunately such examples of this appear to be scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using a service (`DataRepo`) which stores all the data you want to keep globally. For example, you have an `input` where users can type in some side notes regarding their order and they might to see their text again if they navigate back to this very site.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="DataRepo.orderNotes">
```

In your controller, you inject your `DataRepo` service and bind it to the scope:

```
$scope.DataRepo = DataRepo;
```

By doing so, user input will be automatically stored into the `DataRepo` service.

Comment: The solution looks exactly what I was proposing to do.  So basically I could create a couple of methods on the service, e.g. `addOrder()` which will set the `addOrder` property to `true` and erase the `order` object; and `editOrder(order)` which will set the `addOrder` property to `false` and then populate the `order` property from the `order` parameter?

Comment: Of course you can populate this service with whole objects and functions to better deal with the data. I was just trying to give an easy example of how I am dealing with that problem.